# How to solve "Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views" in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin

This code is taken from pretty complex codebase. Hopefully I extracted relevant parts without missing information. Imagine a fragment/activity displaying your inbox, which contains lot of chats.

The code is roughly like this:

```
fun initData() {
        listChats = ArrayList()
        listChats.add(....))

        chatAdapter!!.updateListChat(listChats)

        getDiscussionList()
}

getDiscussionList(){
    pbChat.visibility = View.VISIBLE
    lvChat.visibility = View.GONE

    listChats.clear();

    // do HTTP GET to populate listChats
    // blah blah blah

    pbChat.visibility = View.GONE
    lvChas.visibility = View.VISIBLE
}
```

Other than displaying/hiding ProgressBar and ListView, most of the work in getDiscussionList() is parsing JSON from HTTP GET and populating listChat properly. This works fine. Now what's missing is auto-refresh feature.

I added a minor modification, now the code looks like this:

```
fun initData() {
        listChats = ArrayList()
        listChats.add(....))

        chatAdapter!!.updateListChat(listChats)

        getDiscussionList()

        activity.runOnUiThread {

            Timer().schedule(5000){
                getDiscussionList()
            }
        }
 }
```

I run this code and eventually will get "Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.". How to properly execute getDiscussionList() every X seconds, then?

Comment: why is there a timer in your runonuithread? why not use android's alarm or jobschedule functionality instead? that way you can let the user set how fast he wants to update the chat and also not update the chat erroneously when the app is backgrounded

Comment: What will happen if user leave this screen before 5 second ? Its gonna Crash ?

Comment: @kkarakk I guess I'm wrong then. TImer().schedule(5000) means wait for 5 seconds and then execute this task, not repeat this task per 5 seconds, right?

Comment: no you're not wrong but i can't think of any reason you would want to wait and update ui unless you were repeating the functionality

Answer (score 2):

Timer.schedule creates a non ui thread to run the code, so you are actually running getDiscussionList() in a non ui thread (what the error is saying);

you're code should look like this:

```
getDiscussionList(){
    //do some stuff permitted in ui and the timer thread, cause apparently both ui and non ui threads run this;
    activity.runOnUiThread {//or call some handler
         //do stuff permitted in the ui thread; e.g. accessing views
    }
}

fun initData() {
    //some code
    Timer().schedule(5000){
            getDiscussionList()
    }
 }
```

Comment: This points exactly to the root cause and should be accepted.